# Recovering data from ZFS mirror

Tags: solaris, zfs

I have two disks from an old server that I believe were a mirrored set. I placed them in a new server and tried to do a zpool import but nothing was found. Does that mean the data that was on them previously is lost or is there some way to reconstitute the pool?

Comment: I think these disks may have been have been offlined and replaced with larger ones. Can I still use them to assemble a zpool?

Comment: Were the old server and new one using the same CPU architecture ? What old and new Solaris releases ? Was hardware or ZFS mirroring used ?

Answer (score 0):

May be your old mirror set was a hardware one, not the ZFS. Depends on your HW. Check partitions table with `prtvtoc /dev/rdsk/c#t#d#` if something is there. ZFS can reconstruct its pools no matter what order are disks placed in.